# When should a question tagged {pgf-tikz}, {pstricks}, {asymptote}, etc also be tagged {diagrams}?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Here is the current wiki for the [diagrams] tag:

> {diagrams} is for general questions about vector graphics created programmatically inside a (La)TeX document. For questions about specific packages, use the appropriate tag, e.g. {tikz-pgf} or {pstricks}. For questions about inclusion of external graphic files, use {graphics} instead.

This wiki does not specify whether a tag such as [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) should be used *in addition* to the [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag, or *instead of* it.

Based on the results of [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3452/484), the community consensus seems to be that it is often acceptable to post, e.g., a pstricks answer to a tikz question for the benefit of the community, even if such an answer is less useful to the OP. As an extension of this policy, it seems to me that a question that is likely to attract answers using more than one drawing program ought to have the [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag added in addition to a more specific tag such as [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf).

If this tagging policy were followed, it would, potentially, make it slightly easier to search for questions on a specific type of drawing problem (e.g., how to draw nested spheres). However, a much bigger effect is that it would be easier for someone who likes to provide pstricks, MetaPost, or Asymptote answers to (say) tikz questions, since the [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag would help to identify the fraction of tikz questions general enough for this to make sense. (Full disclosure: I have been known to provide Asymptote answers to TikZ questions.) Depending on the views of the community, this could be seen as either a positive or a negative thing.

Thus, the question: **If a question about a drawing package is general enough that an answer using a different drawing package could be beneficial to the community, should that question be given the [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag in addition to a package-specific tag?**

The ultimate goal of this question is to improve the [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag wiki to clarify this issue.

Comment: For residents that's a good idea but newcomers don't need to know our intricate subtleties. I'm not sure if they ever read the wikis when they are tagging. So we have to enforce it and that is surely going to cause unnecessary tension. I think various answers are just fine and encouraging different workflows is beneficial to all of us.

Comment: I don't think adding the word "also" or "instead" to the tag wiki at an appropriate place would create much confusion. And my general impression is that retagging a question creates much less tension than almost any other kind of modification.

Comment: Yes indeed. But if the newcomers don't do it we have to do it for them and that's extra work no? MAybe I misunderstood.

Comment: As I see it, such a guideline would be at least partly about resolving any questions that might come up. If no one cares enough about retagging a particular question to want to enforce the guideline, I don't see a real problem. If a user asks consistently good questions, then sooner or later someone will care enough to retag a question and the user will learn better tagging procedures. But this may not be the point of view of the rest of the community.

Comment: I found that very thing decidedly confusing. I wound up going with both tags (pgf-tikz and diagrams) because it makes sense to tag both the topic and the package, but the word “also” would do wonders for the clarity of the tag wiki. (FWIW, I *do* read the tag wikis to figure out which one to use, but I'm weird …)

Comment: @LukeMaurer :-)

Answer (score 5):

I have proposed short edits to the tag wiki for [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) with the words "also or instead," meant to clarify that

**proposed optional [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) while using [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks), [metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapost), and [asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote) tags**

> [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag is compatible with  [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks), [metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapost), and [asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote) tags for specific packages without implying any policy to be enforced.

I have also proposed edits that append statements that "this tag is compatible with [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams)" to the wikis for [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks), [metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapost), and [asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote). The intention is to draw users' attention to the [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag just in case they would like to use it.

Hopefully, these additions will clarify the policy for the few of us who care, without creating any conflicts.